# Azure deltalake read from Java

Tags: java, azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I am trying to read data from the data that is saved in my datalake azure portal. Here is the code that I am using

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World New!" );
        
        // Set your Azure Storage account name and key
        String azureClientId = "<azure-client-id>";
        String azureClientSecret = "<azure-client-secret>";
        String azureStorageAccountName = "<storage-name>";

        // Create a Spark configuration
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("PSDeltaLakeDemoRG");
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate();

        // // Set Azure Storage configuration
        // spark.conf().set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem");
        // spark.conf().set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "SharedKey");
        // spark.conf().set("fs.azure.account.key." + azureStorageAccountName, azureStorageAccountKey);

        // spark.conf().set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem");
        spark.conf().set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "OAuth");
        spark.conf().set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider");
        spark.conf().set("fs.azure.account.auth.oauth2.client.id", azureClientId);
        spark.conf().set("fs.azure.account.auth.oauth2.client.secret", azureClientSecret);
        spark.conf().set("fs.azure.account.auth.oauth2.client.endpoint", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token");
        spark.conf().set("spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled", "true");
        // Define the Azure Storage container and file path
        String containerName = "<container-name>";
        String filePath = "mnt/datalake/Output/YellowTaxis.delta";

        // Read data from Azure Storage into a DataFrame
        String azurePath = "abfss://" + containerName + "@" + azureStorageAccountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net/" + filePath;
        
        Dataset<Row> data = spark.read().format("delta").load(azurePath);
        // DeltaTable deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, azurePath);
        // Dataset<Row> data = deltaTable.toDF();
        // Perform operations on the data (e.g., show the content)
        data.show();

        // Stop the Spark session
        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

This is the error that I am getting

```
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
ANTLR Tool version 4.9.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7ANTLR Runtime version 4.9.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7ANTLR Tool version 4.9.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7ANTLR Runtime version 4.9.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7Exception in thread "main" Unable to load key provider class.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AbfsConfiguration.getTokenProvider(AbfsConfiguration.java:477)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.initializeClient(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:814)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.<init>(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.initialize(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaTableUtils$.findDeltaTableRoot(DeltaTable.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource$.parsePathIdentifier(DeltaDataSource.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.x$1$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.x$1(DeltaTableV2.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.rootPath$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.rootPath(DeltaTableV2.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog(DeltaTableV2.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.toBaseRelation(DeltaTableV2.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:177)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:186)
        at com.example.App.main(App.java:48)
```

Dependencies that I am using is mentioned below.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version> <!-- Use the appropriate Spark version -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
        <artifactId>delta-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version> <!-- Use the appropriate Delta Lake version -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-azure</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version> <!-- Use the appropriate Hadoop Azure version -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

Can someone please suggest if I am missing anything.

Note: I am able to access same data from the workspace that i have created in azure portal using spark and same configuration details.

Comment: look into stack trace and search for "caused by" entries - your current error message is incomplete